NameError: 'visual_context' is not defined when using multi-threaded libraries in Python Script
I'm a beginner in python, I'm working on a multi-modal AI assistant project using various Python libraries, and I'm encountering a NameError: 'visual_context' is not defined issue in my script. The error seems to be related to multi-threading, particularly when initializing and using multiple threads from these libraries.
Here's the output:
Exception in thread Thread-2 (threaded_listen):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Erater\anaconda3\envs\Alfred\Lib\threading.py", line 1045, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Erater\anaconda3\envs\Alfred\Lib\threading.py", line 982, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Erater\anaconda3\envs\Alfred\Lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 561, in threaded_listen
    with source as s:
  File "C:\Users\Erater\anaconda3\envs\Alfred\Lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 174, in __enter__
    assert self.stream is None, "This audio source is already inside a context manager"
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AssertionError: This audio source is already inside a context manager

The script uses the following libraries:
faster_whisper for speech-to-text
speech_recognition for voice input
pyaudio for audio playback
cv2 (OpenCV) for webcam capture
google.generativeai for image analysis
groq for fast response
Here is a simplified version of the code:
import os
from faster_whisper import WhisperModel
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio
import cv2

# Initialize WhisperModel
num_cores = os.cpu_count()
whisper_model = WhisperModel('base', device='cpu', compute_type='int8', cpu_threads=num_cores // 2, num_workers=num_cores // 2)

# Initialize recognizer and microphone
r = sr.Recognizer()
source = sr.Microphone()

# Initialize PyAudio
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# Webcam settings
HTTP = 'http://'
IP_ADDRESS = '192.168.1.3'
URL = HTTP + IP_ADDRESS + ':4747/mjpegfeed?640x480'
web_cam = cv2.VideoCapture(URL)

def wav_to_text(audio_path):
    segments, _ = whisper_model.transcribe(audio_path)
    text = ''.join(segment.text for segment in segments)
    return text

def callback(recognizer, audio):
    prompt_audio_path = 'prompt.wav'
    with open(prompt_audio_path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(audio.get_wav_data())
    prompt_text = wav_to_text(prompt_audio_path)
    print(prompt_text)

def start_listening():
    with source as s:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(s, duration=2)
        print("\nSay Alfred followed with your prompt. \n")
        r.listen_in_background(source, callback)

start_listening()


I've tried isolating components. I tested each library individually, and they seem to work fine on their own. The issue arises when they are used together in a multi-threaded context.
Question:
How can I resolve the NameError: 'visual_context' is not defined and avoid threading issues in my script? Is there a better approach to manage multi-threading with these libraries, or any configurations I should change to avoid this conflict?
Thanks in advance for your answers.
